# get_pages and get_posts returning different data?

Tags: api

this is driving me crazy...
I have an admin plugin page that lists pages for a wordpress website. I'm trying to list all the pages using get_pages() but for some reason once pages are published they don't show up anymore - when I use get_posts they show up, but the new draft pages don't :(

Here is the code.. please help

```
//this only displays the new draft pages - once published pages don't show up here
$args = array('post_status' => 'draft, publish');
$pages = get_pages($args);                                                   
foreach ( $pages as $page ) { some html code that displays the page title }

//this piece of code will return all pages onces they were published, 
//even if 'unpublished' later - but will not return new draft pages
global $post;
$args2 = array( 'numberposts' => 50, 'post_status' => 'publish, draft');
$myposts = get_posts( $args2 );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post); 
    ... some HTML code to display the pages
}
```

what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces after the commas in your `post_status` args?

Comment: just tried that - still getting different results here. BTW I'm setting up multisite (can that have something to do with this?)

Comment: you are passing array wrong way, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the array for `post_status` wrong way, Here I updated your code with correction.

*To show List of [pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages)*

```
//To display list of pages
$args = array('post_status' => array('drafts', 'publish'));
$pages = get_pages($args);                                                   
foreach ( $pages as $page ) { 
    // some html code that displays the page title 
}
```

*To show List of [Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts)*

```
// To display list of posts
global $post;
$args2 = array('numberposts' => 50, 'post_status' => array('drafts', 'publish'));
$myposts = get_posts( $args2 );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post); 
    //... some HTML code to display the pages
}
```

> ### Note -
>
> It appears you've got confused with terms `posts` and `pages`.
>
> - `get_pages()` function will return the pages, not the posts
> - `get_posts()` function will return the posts

Comment: thanks amit - that actually doesn't work. I found out that I was not saving page as PAGE when publishing, it defaulted to POST